# Input Box as a dropdown (ComboBox)

Tags: excel, vba

I want my inputBox to be a ComboBox with the following choices: Admin, Associate etc (See my ComboBox code below).

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
With ComboBox1
        .AddItem "Admin"
        .AddItem "Associate"
        .AddItem "Analyst"
        .AddItem "Consultant"
        .AddItem "Senior Consultant"
        .AddItem "Director"
        .AddItem "Principal Consultant"
        .AddItem "Managing Principal"
        .AddItem "Partner"
        .AddItem "Managing Partner"
    End With

End Sub
```

I want to be able to select one of these choices and store it as a string ("Position" in my code) and then re-use it throughout my code.

Also is there anyway to Assign the combobox choices to new strings? e.g

Admin = Adm; Associate= A etc..

Please find my code below:

```
Sub ssNewJoinerM()

Dim YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox As String
Dim QuestionToMessageBox As String

    QuestionToMessageBox = "Do you want to add someone to a Hub ?"

    YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = MsgBox(QuestionToMessageBox, vbYesNo, "New joiner Process")

If YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = vbYes Then

    GoTo Start
    Else: GoTo Finish

End If

Start:

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Dim ws5 As Worksheet
Dim ws6 As Worksheet
Dim ws7 As Worksheet
Dim ws8 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
Set ws2 = ActiveSheet
Set ws3 = ActiveSheet
Set ws4 = ActiveSheet
Set ws5 = ActiveSheet
Set ws6 = ActiveSheet
Set ws7 = ActiveSheet
Set ws8 = ActiveSheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Monthly Movements")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Howard-Marle Hub")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bernard Hub")
Set ws4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Thomas Hub")
Set ws5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Michael Hub")
Set ws6 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Oliver Hub")
Set ws7 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lance Hub")
Set ws8 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("John Hub")

Dim table1 As ListObject
Dim table2 As ListObject
Dim table3 As ListObject
Dim table4 As ListObject
Dim table5 As ListObject
Dim table6 As ListObject
Dim table7 As ListObject
Dim table8 As ListObject
Dim table9 As ListObject
Dim table10 As ListObject
Dim table11 As ListObject
Dim table12 As ListObject
Dim table13 As ListObject
Dim table14 As ListObject
Dim table15 As ListObject

Set table1 = ws2.ListObjects("Table1")
Set table2 = ws2.ListObjects("Table2")
Set table3 = ws1.ListObjects("Table3")
Set table4 = ws3.ListObjects("Table4")
Set table5 = ws3.ListObjects("Table5")
Set table6 = ws4.ListObjects("Table6")
Set table7 = ws4.ListObjects("Table7")
Set table8 = ws5.ListObjects("Table8")
Set table9 = ws5.ListObjects("Table9")
Set table10 = ws6.ListObjects("Table10")
Set table11 = ws6.ListObjects("Table11")
Set table12 = ws7.ListObjects("Table12")
Set table13 = ws7.ListObjects("Table13")
Set table14 = ws8.ListObjects("Table14")
Set table15 = ws8.ListObjects("Table15")

Dim NewJoiner As String
NewJoiner = InputBox("Enter new joiner name in the following format (Surname, First Name)", "Adding New Joiner to Hub")
Dim Position As String
Position = InputBox("Enter new joiner Position (A, C, SC, PC, MP, Partner, Admin, Analyst, Director)", "Assigning New Joiner to a position")
'Input Name and Position and stores it (Could be improved with user form...)
```

Comment: You're adding the list items *every time the selected value is changed*. Not sure that's what you want. The code that goes in the `Change` handler is the code that stores the new selected value for reuse.

Comment: Consider the first code wrong then, it is what i tried but it does not work.

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by "is there anyway to assign the combobox choices to new strings", and it's not clear whether your combobox is on a `UserForm` and if it is, then why is your code using `InputBox`? The `InputBox` function doesn't support this, you need to make your own `UserForm` with a `ComboBox` control for input, with your own OK and Cancel buttons. Looks like you're asking at least 3 questions here. Can you [edit] and narrow it down to one specific issue?

Comment: How do you want your application to respond to user actions for this control? It's not clear that the code you have will necessarily achieve what you're looking for

Comment: It is already stored as `combobox1`, or `sheets("Sheet1").combobox1`

Comment: I want to incorporate the user form in the 2nd piece of code. The user will choose one answer from the combo box choices and  the code will store it as a value for the  variable "Position". Does it make more sense ?

Answer (score 1):

the question you asked consists of three parts.

1. fill the combo box in the correct way
2. use the value of the combo box
3. link the value of the combo box to a synonym such as e.g. "C" for "Consultat"
4. (Style suggestions regarding your code)

**Regarding 1**:
You should fill the combo box when opening the sheet. To achieve that, use the Workbook_Open() Method, which is automatically called, when you open the regarding workbook. "VBAProject" (or whatever the name of your project is) --> "Microsoft Excel Objects" --> "ThisWorkbook"

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' Instead of 1 enter the name of the worksheet which contains the combobox
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ComboBox1
        .AddItem "Admin"
        .AddItem "Associate"
        .AddItem "Analyst"
        .AddItem "Consultant"
        .AddItem "Senior Consultant"
        .AddItem "Director"
        .AddItem "Principal Consultant"
        .AddItem "Managing Principal"
        .AddItem "Partner"
        .AddItem "Managing Partner"
    End With
End Sub
```

The "ComboBox1_Change()" method you used, triggers an event every time the user changes a value of the combo box.

**Regarding 2**:
I think the code is self-explaining regarding that part. You can just reference every time on the combo box value.

```
Dim dropdown        As ComboBox
Dim dropdown_value  As String

Set dropdown = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ComboBox1
dropdown_value = dropdown.Value
```

**Regarding 3**: You should give a little bit more insight what you want to do with that. Depending on the answer to that question, the answer on how to do it will be different.
What you in general have to do is a kind of "mapping". I would suggest to simply use an array and have something like a translating function:

```
Function MappingArray(ByVal input_string As String) As Variant

    ' Size an two-dimensional array
    Dim mapping(0 To 9, 0 To 1)     As Variant
    Dim i                           As Integer

    ' fill the first dimension with mapping of full names
    mapping(0, 0) = "Admin"
    mapping(1, 0) = "Associate"
    mapping(2, 0) = "Analyst"
    mapping(3, 0) = "Consultant"
    mapping(4, 0) = "Senior Consultant"
    mapping(5, 0) = "Director"
    mapping(6, 0) = "Principal Consultant"
    mapping(7, 0) = "Managing Principal"
    mapping(8, 0) = "Partner"
    mapping(9, 0) = "Managing Partner"
    ' fill the second dimension with regarding shortcuts
    mapping(0, 1) = "Ad"
    mapping(1, 1) = "A"
    mapping(2, 1) = "An"
    mapping(3, 1) = "C"
    mapping(4, 1) = "SC"
    mapping(5, 1) = "Dir"
    mapping(6, 1) = "PC"
    mapping(7, 1) = "MPr"
    mapping(8, 1) = "P"
    mapping(9, 1) = "MP"

    ' loop throught the array until you find the value
    For i = LBound(mapping, 1) To UBound(mapping, 1)
        If input_string = mapping(i, 0) Then
            ' assign the opposite value to the function
            MappingArray = mapping(i, 1)
            ' exit, because you are done
            Exit Function
        ElseIf input_string = mapping(i, 1) Then
            ' assign the opposite value to the function
            MappingArray = mapping(i, 0)
            ' exit, because you are done
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    MappingArray = "Error: Value not found"

End Function
```

**Regarding 4**: Stop using "GoTo". Better negate your if statement like:

```
If MsgBox(QuestionToMessageBox, vbYesNo, "New joiner Process") = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

if you have any more questions, feel free to ask.
cheers